# how to close applications using webcam dell integrated webcam?

Tags: windows-7, webcam, dell-latitude, integrated-camera

I am using Dell Latitude. I don't know from when the issue started. I am not able to use my integrated webcam. it is telling "**`Close any other video streaming application to start video.`**". I confirmed this is not a hardware issue by using the webcam in my virtual XP and it worked perfectly there but its not working in my Win 7. I tried uninstalling all my players and applications that i have installed in my pc and tried but not working.

I hope if it was possible to know which port the Dell webcam application is using so that if possible script some kind of code such that the port can be reseted. any suggestions..

**Updates** :-

The Webcam is working on the virtual XP installed on Win 7 perfectly. I tried doing the setting specified in the **[link]**=>[Using and Troubleshooting the Dell Webcam and Dell Webcam Central Software](http://www.dell.com/support/troubleshooting/us/en/19/KCS/KcsArticles/ArticleView?c=aw&l=en&s=dhs&docid=266612) and still the cam is displaying the same message ***"Close other video streaming Application"***

I Installed **Microsoft silverlight** and tested, the webcam in the silverlight configuration is working perfectly fine, On the other side webcam central Application Software showing the Message ***"Close Other Video Streaming Application"***

I ***Connected an another USB Camera*** and checked,here both the cameras are showing the same message.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The article
[Using and Troubleshooting the Dell Webcam and Dell Webcam Central Software](http://www.dell.com/support/troubleshooting/us/en/19/KCS/KcsArticles/ArticleView?c=aw&l=en&s=dhs&docid=266612),
section 2 "Windows XP, Vista or 7 is Installed",
sub-section C "Troubleshooting Webcam Issues" :

> Messages and errors such as **No supported webcam connected, Please
>   plug in a supported device** and **Close the other video streaming
>   application to start video** can be resolved by uninstalling,
>   reinstalling or updating the webcam driver.
>
> The process for uninstalling and reinstalling the webcam driver
>   depends on which Operating System your computer has installed.

For Windows 7 we have this procedure :

1. Change the compatibility setting of the Dell webcam central software to Windows Vista (Service Pack 2). The file is :
   `C:\Program Files (x86)\Dell Webcam\Dell Webcam Central\WebcamDell2.exe`.
   Right-click the file, select Properties, click the Compatibility tab,
   check the box next to "Run this program in compatibility mode for",
   using the drop-down menu select `Windows Vista (Service Pack 2)`,
   click Apply, click OK, then start the Dell Webcam Central Software
2. Reinstall the webcam driver.
   Start Computer Management, click on Device Manager then Imaging deviceş,
   right-click "Integrated webcam or USB camera", click Uninstall then OĶ
   once uninstalled restart the computer.

The article says that for best results the webcam software should also be uninstalled and reinstalled after the drivers are installed
(but remember then to reset the compatibility setting of the Dell webcam central software).

Comment: Hi Thanks for the reponce all these have been tried and still not working.I installed Microsoft silverlight in my PC and tried viewing cam through it and its working perfectly fine. at the same time here its showing the "close the video streaming application" message.

Comment: Does the Dell Webcam work when booting in Safe mode? (The chances are small but worth testing.)

Comment: no.. its not working..!! I installed virtual xp on top of win 7 and checked and cam is working perfectly fine the problem is with win 7.!!

Comment: The problem is surely with an outdated driver that works fine on XP but not on Windows 7. The problem is that the only way to use a driver in XP compatibility mode is exactly as you have done, in virtual XP mode. But see if there is an optional update of a driver in Windows Update (better fully patch the computer except for Bing desktop etc.). Also check in [Dell Support](http://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/19) if there is a newer driver for your exact computer model.

Comment: the driver is updated to the latest version of the available software. In Win 7 itself The Application **Microsoft silverlight** configuration window the cam test works perfectly.And one more update i connected an another usb camera to the laptop and checked now both the cam (integrated and USB camera) are showing the same message.

Comment: You seem to have shown conclusively that the problem is not with the Windows driver but with the Dell Webcam software. It looks like a simple bug and only Dell Support can help (but will probably only refer you the article I quoted above). Use another camera software until Dell fixes the bug (which to truly say I don't believe will happen any time soon - this is not a new bug).

Comment: I had already contacted Dell Support and they are suggesting me to reinstall the OS which i don't think Its a good solution for me. Please see the last update point which i have mentioned in my question. I connected an another USB camera and checked but there again the same message is displayed.

Comment: I take it that the message for the 2nd camera is by the Dell software. Reinstalling the OS is dummy advice and most likely won't help. This is most probably a bug in the Dell software on Windows 7 and they are clueless.

Comment: Seems like another user is having the same prob but with Asus. check this Stack Link [http://superuser.com/q/615467/276625]

Comment: Asus is apparently no better than Dell in software. The question is whether this message is real or bogus. I would say bogus because other applications work properly. The last gasp effort before giving up on the Dell software is to see if the camera is really in use. For how-to do that see [in this post](http://superuser.com/questions/335116/finding-out-which-app-is-using-the-webcam) the two highest-voted answers.

Comment: i just tried the solution provided there and the search resulted in the process explorer is 0. :(

Comment: My conclusion is then that the error is bogus. Since Dell Support just fobs you off, take one of the many available alternatives. Examples: [ManyCam](http://manycam.com/), [Yawcam](http://www.yawcam.com/), [Webcam Publisher](http://www.wheresjames.com/index.php?page=wjwp2) and [SplitCam](http://www.splitcamera.com/).

Comment: @harrymc: I updated my answer with the new possible solutions

Answer (score 2):

I just read [this Lifehacker article](http://lifehacker.com/find-out-what-windows-program-is-using-your-webcam-on-w-1582372561) about finding out the processes that are currently using the webcam on your computer. It worked for me. You might want to give it a shot.

Here's what you need to do (instructions from Lifehacker):

1. Start Device Manager
   (<kbd>WIN</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> → "devmgmt.msc" → OK)
2. Find your webcam among the list of devices (check under Imaging Devices)
3. Open the properties window of the device and switch to the **Details** tab 
    (Right click → Properties → Details)
4. In the dropdown menu, select **Physical Device Object Name** and copy the string
   (Right click → Copy)
5. Download [Process Explorer](http://live.sysinternals.com/procexp.exe)
6. Make sure you have opened Process Explorer in Administrator Mode
   (File → Show Details for All Processes)
7. Hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> and enter the string you copied earlier
   (it should be something like **\Device\000000XX**)
8. Hit the Search button and you should see a list of processes using the webcam (if there are any)

This could potentially smoke out any webcam hijacking spyware that's running on your computer.

**UPDATE:**

It's possible that you're facing these problems on account of a spyware infection. An unwanted process may be using the webcam because of which other processes are denied access to it.

Since you say the webcam works fine in a virtual machine running on the host OS (did you install the same Dell webcam driver on the virtual machine that you installed on the host OS or did you let Windows install a generic webcam driver?), I think the problem might have something to do with either:

1. An interfering process
2. The Dell webcam driver

If it's the latter, what you could do is update your virus scanner and schedule a boot time malware scan. The procedure for this varies from one AV product to another. If you use Avast Antivirus, follow the instructions [here](http://schmahl.net/avastbootscan.php). Or you could consider using a bootable rescue disk like [Sophos Bootable Anti-Virus](http://www.sophos.com/en-us/support/knowledgebase/52011.aspx) or [Kaspersky Rescue Disk](http://support.kaspersky.com/4162) to scan your computer at boot time.

You might also want to scan your machine with [Malwarebytes Anti-Malware](http://www.malwarebytes.org/) and if nothing else works, try [ComboFix](http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/download/combofix/) as your last resort.

However, if the problem still persists after the malware scan, the webcam driver could be the culprit. If that's the case, you could try [uninstalling the Dell webcam drivers completely from the Device Manager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff553572%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Make sure that before you uninstall the driver, you note down all the driver related files (DLLs, EXEs, etc.) that will be removed. You can do this by clicking on the "Driver Details" button in the driver properties window:
[image: Driver File Details]

After driver uninstall is complete, verify that all the driver files were indeed deleted. If not, delete them individually. Now do a hardware scan in Device Manager (Action → Scan for hardware changes) and let Windows Update find the required drivers automatically. Windows might install a generic webcam driver and that might do the trick.

Comment: The poster has done that and the result was: "the search resulted in the process explorer is 0".

Comment: I have already done this and i was not able to find any other programs using my web cam.

Comment: I uninstalled the camera and checked if all the driver files were deleted.It was not.So i took a backup of the files and deleted and restarted and tried to install the driver at that time i got a message in the device manager as "Windows cannot load the device driver for this hardware. The driver may be corrupted or missing. (Code 39)" I restored the files and the driver got updated successfully,but still after that the issue still exists.

Comment: You do not want to install the same driver again. Try uninstalling the driver, removing the left over files and rebooting. Then start Device Manager and click on Action -> Scan for hardware changes. Windows should find the webcam as a newly detected hardware. Make sure you are connected to the Internet and update the driver for the webcam. Let Windows search Windows Update for a driver.

Comment: Its done!! and installed but after that also not working..

Comment: Did you try the other solutions I mentioned? The boot time scan with your AV and finally, ComboFix?

Comment: i can't do that I have Kaspersky installed in my PC.

Comment: You could use Kaspersky Rescue Disk I mentioned in my answer. Scan your computer using the rescue disk to make sure you don't have any spyware/malware on your computer.

Comment: unfortunatly that too didnot work. I tried the Rescue Disk Option too.

Comment: This is probably overkill, but as a last ditch attempt, you could try ComboFix as well. It's worked for me on several occasions.